# What is $.ajax data: for?

Tags: jquery

I deleted `var string` and  `$.ajax data:` line and still my script worked fine, so what this is for then?

```
  $(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function() {
    $('#load').fadeIn();
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");


var string = 'id='+ id ;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: string,
   cache: false,
   success: function(){
    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#load').fadeOut();
  }

 });

return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: How would we be able to know what it is for? It is your code...

Comment: You should read the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) first.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to pass the parameter.

If in the server side, `delete.php` and `delete.php?id={id}` just do the same thing, then it's same.

But it should not be same in normal case, it's your code, under your control.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter in the `ajax()` function is where you place data that you want to send with the request to the server.

> **data** (Object, String)
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs...

In you specific case, from what I can see in the code above that you posted.  Your `delete.php` file would receive the data send in the ajax call and you'll be able to see it in the `$_POST` variable in PHP.

Reference - [jQuery `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

When a `class="delete"` is clicked, you're getting the `id` of that element and sending it to `delete.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It contains query string parameters for the server. In this case the ID of the element that has to be deleted.

However since the server seems not to deliver another status but HTTP 200, the success handler is triggered and the element is faded out or something like that, so it seems that the element has been deleted but if you'd refresh its still there.